# Opencart 3 API add products via POST request

Tags: php, post, request, opencart

I'm trying to build a products API in OpenCart 3. I want to insert products via POST request. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is **no** API controller to handle creation of products via the API. Assuming you are using the latest version of Opencart 3, these are the available endpoints - https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/3.0.x.x_Maintenance/upload/catalog/controller/api

Also their documentation does have some information which might help - https://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31915486)

Answer (score 0):

Opencart does not offer product create creation API but you can create your custom API for product creation.

1. catalog/controller/api/custom.php: It's a controller file, and most
   of our application logic resides in this file.
2. catalog/language/en-gb/api/custom.php: It's a language file that
   holds language variables.
3. common.php: This file holds the common code for reusability purposes.
4. login.php: It's a file that demonstrates how to log in to the store
   using the REST API.
5. products.php: It's a file that demonstrates how to fetch products
   using our custom API module.

[More details.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-opencart--cms-26018)